# Typewriter Text with Underscore that types and erases (In a Cycle)

Tags: javascript, animation, typekit

I found an amazing typewriting effect at this website:  http://www.9elements.com

The header shows a brilliant typewriter effect that I want to duplicate, but the code does NOT work in Explorer.  The script types each letter, erases it via backward delete, and then types the next sentence separately.  More importantly, it loops.

I need to find a script that is comparable if not the same.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to start with:

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/typewriter

http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-typewriter